# saving variable in little endian

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, endianness

I want to read a value from file and save it as little endian in assembly. The value in input file is in OCT. I wrote some code which I think should work, but doesn't :/

My thinking: 
I read of course an ascii, so I load it to a buffer. Then I load first byte from buffer to a register, subtract '0' to make it a number instead of character and add it to the bx register. For every next byte I do the same thing but I first move the bits left before adding (because my value is stored on three bits, I move the values by, 3, 6, 9, etc.) I do it 8 times and then save it to a buffer. I save by moving bl part of my register do buffer and then moving bits right by 8 (do it 3 times).

My problem is that I get rubbish in the terminal (I try to display the final buffer at the end) or can't open the file to which I writing the result. I saw in the debugger that during saving phase I end up with negative values, but I can't get my head around as to why.

My code:

```
 .data
 SYSREAD = 0
 SYSWRITE = 1
 SYSOPEN = 2
 SYSCLOSE = 3
 STDOUT = 1
 FREAD = 0
 FWRITE = 1
 SYSEXIT = 60
 EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
 BUFLEN = 1024
 num_in1: .ascii "in.txt\0" # Nazwa pliku musi kończyć się zerowym bajtem
 num_in2: .ascii "in2.txt\0"
 num_out: .ascii "out.txt\0"

.bss
.comm textin, 1024
.comm textin2, 1024
.comm value1, 512
.comm value2, 512
.comm output, 513
.comm output_not_in_endian, 513
.comm result, 1024

.text 
.globl _start

_start:
# clear buffor
mov $512, %rdi 
mov $0, %al

clearing:
dec %rdi
mov %al, value1(, %rdi, 1)
cmp $0, %rdi
jg clearing

mov $512, %rdi

clearing2:
dec %rdi
mov %al, value2(, %rdi, 1)
cmp $0, %rdi
jg clearing2

# opening file
mov $SYSOPEN, %rax
mov $num_in1, %rdi
mov $0, %rsi
mov $0, %rdx
syscall
mov %rax, %r10

# read from file
mov $SYSREAD, %rax
mov %r10, %rdi
mov $textin, %rsi
mov $1024, %rdx
syscall
mov %rax, %r8 
dec %r8

# closing file
mov $SYSCLOSE, %rax
mov %r10, %rdi
mov $0, %rsi
mov $0, %rdx
syscall
mov $0, %r9

loop:
dec %r8 
and $0, %al
mov $0, %rdi                

mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al
movq %rax, %rbx
sub $'0', %bl 
cmp $0, %r8 
jle zapisz

dec %r8
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al 
sub $'0', %al
shl $3, %rax 
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz

dec %r8
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al
sub $'0', %al
shl $6, %rax        
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz

dec %r8
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al
sub $'0', %al
shl $9, %rax        
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz

dec %r8
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al 
sub $'0', %al
shl $12, %rax       
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz

dec %r8 
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al
sub $'0', %al
shl $15, %rax       
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz

dec %r8 
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al 
sub $'0', %al
shl $18, %rax       
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz

dec %r8 
and $0, %rax
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al 
sub $'0', %al
shl $21, %rax       
add %rax, %rbx

zapisz:
mov %bl, value1(, %r9,1)
shr $8, %rbx
inc %rdi
inc %r9
cmp $3, %rdi
jl zapisz

cmp $0, %r8
je zapisz1
jmp loop


zapisz1:
# display
mov $SYSWRITE, %rax
mov $STDOUT, %rdi
mov $value1, %rsi
mov $1024, %rdx
syscall

# opening/creating the result file
mov $SYSOPEN, %rax
mov $num_out, %rdi
mov $FWRITE, %rsi
mov $0644, %rdx
syscall
mov %rax, %r8       # file descriptor to r8

# save to file
mov $SYSWRITE, %rax
mov %r8, %rdi
mov $value1, %rsi
mov $1024, %rdx
syscall

# closing file
mov $SYSCLOSE, %rax
mov %r8, %rdi
mov $0, %rsi
mov $0, %rdx
syscall

# ending
mov $SYSEXIT, %rax
mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %rdi
syscall
```

EDIT: The code worked good. Numbers in buffers are good, but when trying to display them, they get convertet to ascii code. So I'm basically trying display character which ascii code is eg. 3, which is unreadable and ends up printing rubbish.

Also, simplified version, using `cl` register to move bits (fragment only)

```
loop:
dec %r8
and $0, %al
mov $0, %rdi
mov $0, %cl
read:
mov textin(, %r8, 1), %al
shl %cl, %rax
add $3, %cl
add %rax, %rbx
cmp $0, %r8
jle zapisz
dec %r8
and $0, %rax
cmp $21, %cl
jle read
zapisz:
mov %bl, value1(, %r9,1)
shr $8, %rbx
inc %rdi
inc %r9
cmp $3, %rdi
jl zapisz
cmp $0, %r8
je zapisz1
jmp loop
```

Comment: `mov %bl, value1(, %r9,1)` <-- as far as I can tell, `%bl` does not contain a character in the range `'0'..'7'` at this point. Also, on the first "iteration" you move to `%rbx` before subtracting `'0'`, while on the others you subtract first. And please use a loop rather that repeating the same code 8 times - it would make the code much shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Hmm, that's an awful lot of code to dig through. Is there no way you can isolate your problem to a shorter snippet of code? Also, there's an awful lot of *repeated, identical* code here. It looks like the only difference between a lot of these sections is the shift count. Since you can shift by a variable amount stored in the `CL` register, you might consider simplifying (and optimizing) this code using that. You would then have a simple loop that just needed to increment the shift count in `CL`.

Comment: Michael, if it doesn't contain a number, then what? That my problem  in a nutshell. And yeah, I know it's much but I didn't know that I can move it using cl register. I tried using r10 and it didn't work, so I thought I can't use register there. I'll fix that!